# Is there any limitations in fbx for UV's count?

Tags: python, uv, export, unreal-engine

I'm trying to find out, is there any limitations for UV's export from Blender? My situation: I have skeletal mesh in Blender with 6 UVs, which I'm trying to export into Unreal Engine 5.3. I've tried different ways (using usual export, send to unreal addon, better fbx exporting addon) with the same result - I'm getting skeletal mesh with only 4 UV channels. I thought, problem could be in engine, but I can add new uv channel manually inside UE5. And when I'm trying to export static mesh I'm getting as much UVs as I want.

So, I think the problem could be in fbx format or exporter's code. Can somebody, at least, confirm or refute this sentence? I just don't know where to search any information about it. I've tried to google it, but the only thing I found is this forum's [message](https://forum.unity.com/threads/fbx-exporter-not-exporting-uv4-5-6-7.1273364/). That's why I thought the problem could be in fbx.

**Edit**: @scurest assumed the problem could be in Unreal's FBX importer, so I decided to create a simple cube with one bone and 7 UV maps
[image]
[cube.fbx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORu2qWR-JCaodTPDx0cQL7lBgGgaGqNJ/view?usp=sharing). Can somebody try to import it to maya or another software to see if there are all UV maps or something missing?

Comment: Blender itself only allows 8 UVMaps. Exporting and reimporting roundtrips all 8, so I assume it's a limitation inside Unreal.

Comment: @scurest I doubt it, because I can use 8 UVMaps with static meshes in Unreal and I can add 5, 6, 7... UV layouts for skeletal mesh inside Unreal's UV editor.

Comment: Perhaps it's a limitation of Unreal's FBX importer then, but obviously the UVs exist in the FBX file, or Blender wouldn't be able to import them.

Comment: @scurest maybe, you're right, so I edited question. Maybe, somebody can check attached file with another software.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @scurest was almost right, I suppose. I'm not sure if it's correct, but everything I've found is Unreal Engine 5 supports 8 UV layers, but 4 layers reserved for customized UV. And I don't know how to ignore or disable it through import.

There is only one thing I can't understand. I still can create additional layers through built-in UV editor:
[image]